# Enter animation using ConstraintSet

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to make enter animation for activity using ConstraintSet, as it's shown in this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHcfs6rStRo.

The problem is I don't know in which lifecycle method to put code to make the transition visible to user.

In onCreate I'm calling:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_first_keyframe_detail);
topConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_constraint_layout);
constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.layout_detail_top);
```

and then I'd like to call:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(topConstraintLayout);
constraintSet.applyTo(topConstraintLayout);
```

when activity is already visible. Unfortunately I don't find any lifecycle method to do this.

Comment: and when do you want your animation to start? as soon as your `Activity` starts?

Comment: yes, as soon as it starts and is visible to user

Comment: see `android.view.ViewTreeObserver`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransiton()` implementation, you will see that it starts with following check : 
`if (!sPendingTransitions.contains(sceneRoot) && sceneRoot.isLaidOut())` 
Looking at isLaidOut() documentation will make you understand that the view has to be drawn at least once so the animation can be executed :

> Returns true if this view has been through at least one layout since
>   it was last attached to or detached from a window.

However, wrapping the animation launch in a message worked for me. So you should try to do it like :

```
myView.post{ 
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(topConstraintLayout);
    constraintSet.applyTo(topConstraintLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to create animations using ConstraintLayout and ConstraintSet you must first consider that there must be a starting layout and an ending layout

**Step 1: Create your layouts**

create your starting layout and ending layout as you want

--> *suppose the starting layout name is (activity) the ending layout name is (activity_alt)*

**Step 2: Create Animation**

now in the `MainActivity` inside `onCreate` method call your function `foo`

```
    private void foo() {
    var set = false
    val constraint1 = ConstraintSet()
    constraint1.clone(root)
    val constraint2 = ConstraintSet()
    constraint2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_alt)


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root)
            val constraint = if(set) constraint1 else constraint2
            constraint.applyTo(root)
            set = !set
        }
    }
```

Comment: resources
https://proandroiddev.com/creating-awesome-animations-using-constraintlayout-and-constraintset-part-i-390cc72c5f75

Comment: but if beginDelayedTransition is called inside onCreate, then animaton will happen before actvity is visible

Comment: @yogourt IDK you've a problem like that it must work correctly, but here's some useful solutions...

1) as mentioned in the Android life cycle the onCreate is the first thing that's called after that onStart, so what about calling the foo() method from the onStart instead of onCreate

2)in general you can determine when the UI event queue is empty by calling getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync(). That'll block until there's no more UI events to process.

3) you can easily use a timer for to make  a simple delay before calling foo() method